# How to debug a client application using Anonymous Pipes

Tags: c#

I´m using Anonymous Pipes for my C# applications for a server(WPF project, main application) without admin rights and a client(command line tool just for executing some tasks for the server that need admin rights) with admin rights.

The Anonymous Pipes part is based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx

It works fine but my problem is that I can´t seem to debug the client.

The server is the starting project and debugging works fine there. But if I want to debug the client, the pipes have to be provided at startup and handed to the command line

using (PipeStream pipeClient =
                new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, args[0]))

So how do I debug the client? I have to start the Process over the server process, but how do I get visual studio to hold on breakpoints in the client code then? (Both projects are already in the same Visual studio solution)

Comment: If I am understand your problem correctly, you should be able to overcome it by attaching the debugger (VS) to the already running process.

Comment: How do I do that with VS2010 Express C#?

Comment: doesn't vs2010 have a attach debugger to process option? Can you start a second instance of visual studio and use that debugger?

Comment: It looks like Express Editions don´t have it. I would buy Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 if it wouldn´t cost 10.000€ omg

Answer (score 0):

As you've already mentioned in the comments, you can't attach the debugger to another process in VS 2010 Express.

This limitation is removed in VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs). Upgrade and you'll have access to the "Attach to Process..." menu item under **DEBUG**.